# PHP - HTML - when to include external php files

Tags: php

I'm still learning PHP and have a question about the structuring your page and when to include php pages within the current page. As an example I have a page that allows the user to create a new record in a database back end. I first check that the connection to the database is working and if so I display the blank form. At the moment I'm including it as followings:

```
<?php
// show the required file if there were no login  errors
 if (isset($loginError) && $loginError == '')  {
 require 'newContactInc.php'; 
}               
?>
```

but I was wondering before I went too far down this road if that was "best practice" or not. I don't want to find myself with too many mini php files that get included in a parent file, but using this approach allows me to not have to quote and escape the html, e.g. I can use:

```
<div class="form-group">
```

in my include file instead of

```
$html = '<div class=\"form-group\">';
echo $html;
etc
```

Just wondering if there's a "best practice" method to use when you're generating html but only want to conditionally show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a good way of keeping your HTML seperate however if you aren't aiming to reuse that form in other pages you can do the following to include it in your page without needed to echo it as a string:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($loginError) && $loginError == '') : 
?>
<form>    </form>
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

This will only print the form if the condition is met.

Overall though you are better off breaking your pages into reusable components and including them, this is not only a cleaner approach preventing unnecessary duplicate markup but in the event that you want to make a change across the whole site you only need to edit the one file rather than open up every page where that component is used and change it.

Comment: Thanks - I'd seen that structure before but never really understood how it worked. I didn't realise you could split if/end statements across more than 1 <?php ?> block. BTW should that be a semi colon at the end of line 2?

Comment: The colon is the proper syntax. Semicolon will break it.

Comment: I added though that you should keep doing what you are doing as it is a much better way of building web pages with php allowing for more reusability and easier site wide changes.